# Tunnel websockets over socketIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, google-chrome

I'm trying to tunnel chrome's remote debugging port over socket IO.

Where Chrome is running, I have a nodeJS script which pipes data socket IO (base 64 encoded) to chrome & vice versa:

```
var net = require('net');

    chat.on('rdp-data', function(rdpData) {

        var client = net.Socket();
        client.connect(9222, '127.0.0.1', function() {
            console.log('rdp-data', new Buffer(rdpData.data, 'base64').toString('utf8'));
            client.write(new Buffer(rdpData.data, 'base64').toString('utf8'));
        });

        // when we get packets back from the client
        client.on('data', function(data) {
            // write those packets back to the server
            //sock.write(data);
            console.log('rdp-data-reply' + rdpData.request);
            chat.emit('rdp-data-reply' + rdpData.request, new Buffer(data).toString('base64'));
            console.log('sent2 ',new Buffer(rdpData.data, 'base64').toString('utf8'));
        });

        // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
        client.on('close', function(data) {
            console.log('CLOSED: ');
        });
        client.on('error', function(data) {
            console.log('error: ',data);
        });
    });
```

On another machine I have a nodeJS script which listens on 9222, and pipes data to & from socket IO:

```
net.createServer(function(sock) {
                // We have a connection - a socket object is assigned to the connection automatically
                console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);

                var request = Math.random();
                console.log('addListner rdp-data-reply'+request);
                connectedDeviceSockets[IDdata.sn].on('rdp-data-reply' + request, function (data) {
                    console.log('rdp data reply ' + request, new Buffer(data, 'base64').toString('utf8'));
                    sock.write(new Buffer(data, 'base64').toString('utf8'));
                });

                sock.on('data', function(data) {
                    connectedDeviceSockets[IDdata.sn].emit('rdp-data', {
                        data: new Buffer(data).toString('base64'),
                        request: request
                    })
                });

                // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
                sock.on('close', function(data) {
                    console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
                });
                sock.on('error', function(data) {
                    console.log('ERROR: ' + data);
                });
            }).listen(9222, '0.0.0.0');

            console.log('Server listening on 9222');
```

This all works perfectly, I can load the remote debugging port in my browser on the other machine. All the HTML, JS & CSS load. But when devtools tries to do a ws:// request, it fails & my tunnel does not log anything. If I kill both nodeJS & setup a tunnel with `ssh -L` it all works perfectly.

I also tried this with just the `net` package's sockets, and it worked fine, that example is here - https://github.com/joshribakoff/devtools-proxy

I think the problem is something related to trying to tunnel a websocket through a websocket (since devtools uses websockets itself). But why is my script any different from piping the traffic with SSH?

I also found some npm modules that expose a CLI to do this but I want to re-use an existing socketIO connection in my app, not shell out to another connection.

I tried to add logging, but I could not find anything related to the ws:// request devtools makes. Here's some screenshots of me running devtools on the page running devtools. All the assets are loading thru the proxy, except the websocket.

[image: Devtools can load all assets thru the proxy, except the websocket]

[image: No frames are shown]

Comment: Uhh, socket.io already runs on top of a webSocket so it doens't make a whole lot of sense to then try to tunnel a webSocket over that.   If you want to support a webSocket connection, why don't you just instantiate a webSocket server?

Comment: And you don't have to shell out to another app to add support for a webSocket connection.  You can just start up a webSocket server in your same nodejs process (on a different port).

Comment: Also keep in mind that an incoming webSocket connection has a handshake process that involves starting life as an http connection and then upgrading to a webSocket connection and exchanging some security credentials while doing that which are required for understanding the data frame .  Are you supporting all that in your tunnel?

Comment: Hi. Simple. I have a device behind a restrictive firewall which I want to use chrome remote debugging. Chrome remote debugging only listens on localhost. To access remotely, I have to tunnel it. I already have an existing socketIO connection in my app to this device. However when I tunnel devtools, it tries to open its own websocket & fails. Basically I want actual remote debugging.

Comment: >  involves starting life as an http connection ....


Right which is why its confusing that my proxy handles the other assets & logs to the terminal for each file, but does not log any output to my terminal about an attempted ws:// request. My node proxy seems to not even be aware of any connection attempt.

Comment: >You can just start up a webSocket server in your same nodejs process (on a different port) .... unfortunately we're only allowed to communicate to the device on one port, no additional connections are allowed by the firewall. So this has to tunnel it over socketIO, no other options.

Comment: > Are you supporting all that in your tunnel? ... I'm attempting to build a protocool agnostic proxy/tunnel, I'm not supporting anything other than piping raw data around. I want to do what ssh -L does.

Comment: Are you saying that your plain TCP server (the one in your second code block) does not see anything from an incoming webSocket connection to that host on port 9222?

Comment: >  why don't you just instantiate a webSocket server? .... Chrome already is running with --remote-debugging-port and so chrome is the server. I'm trying to put a proxy in front of that.

Comment: Correct the TCP server does not see any incoming ws connection.

Comment: Not sure what entirely you are trying to do here but where is the ws request going? If it is to an invalid host name no request will ever get sent. SSH tunnels name resolution, arp, etc. That isn't going to happen over your tunnel.

Comment: ws://127.0.0.1:9223/devtools/page/CEC9ECC6-F9C2-43BD-8AC6-688899B302B9 and the part about SSH tunneling DNS depends on context. I'm not talking about a socks proxy. Keep in mind it works with node's sockets, see github repo. For some reason introducing socketIO/base64 seems to break it.